# Make editText can type but text not change in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a editText:

```
<EditText
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edittext_cursor"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorBlackHintText"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/font"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:id="@+id/idEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:hint="Type something"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
```

When anyone typing, it will call the function:

```
        EditText idEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idEditText);
        idEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            ChooseText(); // here
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

ChooseText() function will show list then people can choose one of them.

It mean, when anyone try to change editText, the text of editText cannot be changed, the list and will show and this text will change in later, people cannot change this text by themselves.

The most important thing is people  see text in editText not change.
Any helps. Thank!

Comment: you can use a spinner, that is what i get from your question

Comment: Please make clear what "people cannot change this text by themselves" means ?

Comment: use autocomplete textview

Comment: "people cannot change this text by themselves" : people can typing, but text in editText not change, and show activity contains list, button,... to choose.

Comment: spinner and autocomplete textview, It look good but my list more complex, it will contain editText, button in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call ChooseText() function on afterTextChanged() method

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   ChooseText();
}


<EditText         
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/idEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:hint="Type something"/>
```

try this

```
 @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       s.clear();
    }
```

Clicklistener

```
 idEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            ChooseText();
        }
    });
```

Comment: In my case, people can typing, but text in editText not change, and show activity contains list, button,... to choose. The most important thing is people  see text in editText not change.

Comment: Can you post your ChooseText() function?

Comment: It start another activity, but activity just have some control and it not important. My goal is people typing editText, but people will see editText not change :)

Comment: just try after delete android:textCursorDrawable from your xml

Comment: It not working. By the way android:textCursorDrawable just change UI.

Comment: try with the Edittext properties i included in my answer to make sure problem is not on your xml.will you see edittext hint on your activity?

Comment: I did it, but I still see my text I typing.

Comment: It will call public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 2 times.

Comment: add there a condition for checking empty value

Comment: If people choose something, then change text again, how to check it. How to set text with before change? look like s.setText....?

Comment: Try with OnClickListener of you edittext instead of TextWatcher.i hope this will help you.i added code in my answer

Comment: :) My OnClick function is calling the another function. It don't work together.

Answer (score 1):

From what you are trying to do it seems more like a Spinner functionality. Where you want user to select from a fixed list of possible texts (values).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Updated:
Checkout AutoCompleteTextView, maybe that matches what you are trying to do.

For the functionality you want, i suppose it would be better to have EditText + Spinner. And a Button to select between the two. 
Make Layout such that EditText and Spinner overlay each other. By default have Spinner  setVisibility to VISIBLE and EditText to GONE. 
So normally user selects from list of items in spinner. When user is in a situation where none of the spinner list items are OK and needs to edit Text, he/she can press a Button you provide. 
In OnClick of the button you make Spinner setVisibility GONE and EditText setVisibility VISIBLE. So now user has a EditText to enter Custom Text.

Comment: Thank for reply, but I want people cannot typing any characters, when typing, a default list will show immediately.

Comment: When you don't want people to type then EditText is point less. I think you want people to click on some input field and when they do so, you give them a list of options to select. If so, this is exactly what Spinner does. You need to change your EditText to spinner.

Comment: It look good but I want use UI editText, and my list more complex, it will contain editText, button in the future.

Comment: This very awesome, but my goal is people typing editText, but people will see editText not change. By the way, the list shown under editText not accept in my case, a another activity will contains it, and it is a custom list follow options of them :)

Answer (score 0):

How about AutoCompleteTextView? This is an editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically while the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

Find more examples [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: It look good but my list more complex, it will contain editText, button in the future.